# How to work on the ASP.NET in Ubuntu?

Tags: microsoft

I want to work on the ASP.NET in Ubuntu. I use mono but it lack some of the features. It doesn't have the toolbar and not any designing tools. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Update: Wine is apparently not an option. As stated in the comments, ASP.NET/Visual Studio does not work under Wine.

Wine (a Windows emulator) may be an option.

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Then look in Winetricks (which is installed along with Wine) to see if it has a listing for ASP.NET. If it does, you should install it through Winetricks.

If you don't see it in Winetricks, download the official, Microsoft ASP.NET installer like you would on Windows (as an .exe) and open up the installer with Wine. It will install to a virtual C:\ drive in ~/.wine, and shortcuts that the installer creates should automatically be converted to .desktop files and placed in the appropriate place, allowing you to search for and launch ASP.NET just like any other Ubuntu application.

Comment: asp.net is not an application it is aWeb Development framework, and you wont beat mono + monodevelop for using from ubuntu.

Comment: ASP.NET is a web framework. however, i was referring to the official microsoft IDE for ASP.NET.

Comment: That would be called visual studio and no it does not work on wine.

Comment: Okay, sorry. I thought Visual Studio had different editions/download versions (like Visual Studio specifically for ASP.NET/C*/etc) or something.

Answer (score 1):

While Visual Studio is not supported on Linux, there is a fine Mono specific development environment that does...Monodevelop.  http://monodevelop.com/  If you want to develop ASP.Net on Linux, this is the tool I suggest you use.